# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space: java reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I use java reflection in the code like this:

```
Method method = LogFactory.class.getDeclaredMethod("getContextClassLoader");
method.setAccessible(true);
ClassLoader classLoader = (ClassLoader)method.invoke(null);
LogFactory.release(classLoader);
```

I use `jprofiler` can see many class like this `sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11`

these classes are increased per call

```
sun.reflect.BootstrapConstructorAccessorImpl
sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl
sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl
sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader
```

I think this is why PermGen space increase, how to clean these classes?

Comment: Why not create more perm space?

Comment: Maybe I should do more test, I use eclipse debug the code and jprofiler attach it.

Comment: @JermaineXu default perm space is 128MB, but it reach after a month

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505274/what-for-sun-jvm-creates-instances-of-sun-reflect-delegatingclassloader-at-runti

Comment: Welcome to SO. ^-^ @Fatkun

Comment: @Perception thanks Perception. It works

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a pretty nice article discussing about [potential native memory use in reflection delegating classloaders](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566549).

> When using Java reflection, the JVM has two methods of accessing the
> information on the class being reflected. It can use a JNI accessor,
> or a Java bytecode accessor. If it uses a Java bytecode accessor, then
> it needs to have its own Java class and classloader
> (sun/reflect/GeneratedMethodAccessor class and
> sun/reflect/DelegatingClassLoader). Theses classes and classloaders
> use native memory. The accessor bytecode can also get JIT compiled,
> which will increase the native memory use even more. If Java
> reflection is used frequently, this can add up to a significant amount
> of native memory use. The JVM will use the JNI accessor first, then
> after some number of accesses on the same class, will change to use
> the Java bytecode accessor. This is called inflation, when the JVM
> changes from the JNI accessor to the bytecode accessor. Fortunately,
> we can control this with a Java property. The
> sun.reflect.inflationThreshold property tells the JVM what number of
> times to use the JNI accessor. If it is set to 0, then the JNI
> accessors are always used. Since the bytecode accessors use more
> native memory than the JNI ones, if we are seeing a lot of Java
> reflection, we will want to use the JNI accessors. To do this, we just
> need to set the inflationThreshold property to zero.

If you are on a Oracle JVM then you would only need to set:

```
-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=2147483647
```

If you are on IBM JVM, then you would need to set:

```
-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=0
```

Please note that both JVMs differ in the way they interpret.

Comment: -Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=0 will make all invoke to use GeneratedMethodAccessor (jdk6u51 macosx mountain lion). set it to a big value (Integer.MAX_VALUE) will be fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on a Oracle JVM then you would only need to set:

```
sun.reflect.inflationThreshold=2147483647
```

If you are on IBM JVM, then you would need to set:

```
-Dsun.reflect.inflationThreshold=0
```

Please note that both JVMs differ in the way they interpret.

Reference for more details:

[inflation_system_properties](https://blogs.oracle.com/buck/entry/inflation_system_properties)

[native memory use](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566549)