# DelegatingClassLoader instances causing OutOfMemoryError: metaspace

Tags: java, reflection, jvm, classloader

Our application uses object serialization/deserialization and while profiling we observe that this results in too many DelegatingClassLoaders in metaspace. And over the period of time application results OutOfMemoryError.

Quick search we found that JVM's reflection optimization is the reason and was also mentioned at

- [What for Sun JVM creates instances of sun.reflect.DelegatingClassLoader at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505274/what-for-sun-jvm-creates-instances-of-sun-reflect-delegatingclassloader-at-runti)
- https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/potential-native-memory-use-reflection-delegating-classloaders

But the suggested options 'sun.reflect.noInflation' and 'sun.reflect.inflationThreshold' do not work for OpenJDK 11

Is there any other option to solve this problem?

Comment: The reimplementation happened in Java 18. But it’s indeed the simplest solution. But unless excessive class reloading happens, the required amount of metaspace should be finite.

Comment: Github repo changes were done via https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8305104 are part of jdk 22; could you provide bit more information about the change in jdk 18 that I can go through - Thank you

Comment: found it in the description of the call - https://openjdk.org/jeps/416

Comment: Right, 18. Not sure why I wrote 12 there.

Comment: Any clue why 'sun.reflect.noInflation' and 'sun.reflect.inflationThreshold' options dont work with OpenJDK11 ?

Comment: I don’t know any reason why these properties shouldn’t work. I just verified that their support code is still there.